# Query taking very long time in 12C environment, but the same query is taking just a few seconds in 10G production environment

Tags: oracle, performance, query-performance

We are migrating a database from 10G to 12C and currently we are testing in a dummy 12C production environment.

Particularly 3 SQL queries are taking almost 50 min. time to complete and show the output whereas the same query in our current production (Oracle 10G) environment is taking just a few seconds. Could any one help me on what  direction I should go to resolve the problem?

Comment: Hi there, welcome to the site. People tend to like queries, table definitions and execution plans around here. Please read through [help us help you](http://dba.blogoverflow.com/2012/06/help-us-help-you/)

Answer (score 1):

I'd start investigation with the following:

1. Check physical servers parameters like CPU, physical memory, hard drive speed, network , etc, and make sure they are comparable (ideally identical) .
2. Check Oracle memory settings (`memory_target`) on both servers
3. Make sure `dbms_stats` procedures were executed on new server after copying database  (at least `GATHER_DATABASE_STATS`)
4. Check if Optimizer mode (`ALL_ROWS`/`FIRST_ROWS`) is set to the same value on both servers
5. Check value of `CURSOR_SHARING`
6. Remove/disable outlines if any on new server .

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your quick turn around. We have compared all the above parameters and found same for both the environment. Could you please suggest something else ?

Comment: Check execution plan for those queries. It's possible that your new server has bad statistics .  I'd suggest trying `RULE` hint with slow queries to verify if stats are a culprit.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use the parameter [OPTIMIZER_FEATURES_ENABLE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/initparams158.htm) as a quick fix.

Comment: I can see that, in 10G (current production env.) when query is getting executed it is creating multiple session for the same query, but in 12C env. it is creating one and only one session. Is this the problem? So what we have to do in Database so that it creates multiple sessions? Please advice. Thanks, Rudy

Comment: That sounds like parallel is enabled. Check to see if the table you are querying has a certain parallel set, `SELECT TABLE_NAME, degree FROM all_tables WHERE TABLE_NAME='MyTableName'`. If the table does not have parallel set, it may be that the session that is executing is enabling parallelism.